# MVC Razor Web Grid- Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 webgrid. I am displaying the data in a webgrid and before displaying the data I have to calculate the number of days between start date and end date.  I am using the following code.

```
  int  noOfAbsenceDays = item.AbsEnd?(item.AbsEnd.Subtract(item.AbsStart)).Days:               (item.DateTime.Now.Subtract(item.AbsStart)).Days;
```

It complains about this error

```
   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'bool'
```

I don't know where it is coming from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

int noOfAbsenceDays = **item.AbsEnd == null** ? (item.AbsEnd.Subtract(item.AbsStart)).Days : (item.DateTime.Now.Subtract(item.AbsStart)).Days;